# Getting commit tree code from github based on commit id using Ruby Githubapi

Tags: ruby, github

I need to get code from github based on commit id. I am using "github_api" gem and my app authenticates the user using Github.

For example,if the user gives the commit id what I need is to get the tree url and fetch the code from the file and returns the code

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I implemented the above using "github_api" ad here is code to get it done.

```
git = Github.new
github.git_data.trees.get  'username', 'repo', 'commit_sha'
```

This gives a json formatted data and you can get the value of the parameter based on your requirement

Thanks Github API.